# What is wrong with formula: =IF(A1>B4:D4,1,0)?

Tags: excel, formula

Question 1
What is wrong with formula?

```
 =IF(A1>B4:D4,1,0)
```

I want if cell `A1` is greater than set of cells (`B4:D4`) then it returns 1.
Answered

Question 2:
How can i select/indentify two MAX values from set of cells? I want to count two max values.
For example:

```
(header) A B C D E
(row1)   1 5 4 1 3
```

It should return

```
(header) F G H I J
(row1)   0 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: what do you need the top 2 values for?

Comment: Why is `1` one of the top two values??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For top 2 values I would use the LARGE function

```
=IF(A1>LARGE(B4:D4,2),1,0)
```

The LARGE function returns the nth largest value, so LARGE(B4:D4,1) would be equivalent to MAX(B4:D4), but LARGE(B4:D4,2) returns the 2nd largest value

Comment: Thanks, for your answer but it seems it doesn't work for me.
I have a set of range of numbers, from each row i should indentify two max values. I insert your formula to another cell next to numbers but it only shows 1 highest number.

Comment: It could be that the reference needs to be fixed to $B$4:$D$4, otherwise I've misunderstood your question, what are the values in B4:D4?

Comment: yea, sorry for bad clarification. Let me try again. I have set of numbers few in row and thusand in a column. For example:
A B C D E F
6 4 5 6 7 8
3 5 6 9 8 5
5 11 3 5 2 10
4 7 5 6 4 10
7 3 4 5 6 11
So, what i need is to return (in other cells or same doesn't matter) to Max numbers from each row. So, i can count which column has max numbers (can use 1 instead too)

Comment: Ok, I think I was getting confused by the reference to different rows. If your range starts in A1, what it looks like you want is =IF(A1>=LARGE($A1:$F1,2),1,0) in cell G1 then you can copy that formula across to column L and down to the bottom of your range.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean bigger than the max of them:

```
   =IF(A1>MAX(B4:D4),1,0)
```